# Would I use で if I want to say “drawing in an art program”

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-で

I feel like this is wrong, but I’m not entirely sure, if I wanted to say “my first time drawing in Paint Tool Sai” would this sentence be correct?

ペイントツールSAIで初めて描画

Comment: Nothing wrong with で, but the rest of your sentence...

Answer (score 1):

Your use of で is perfectly fine. 描画 is a suru-verb meaning "to draw" or "(an act of) drawing". It is more suitable for geometric or technical drawing, like what you make with a CAD tool, a graph tool or Adobe Illustrator. An artwork typically created with SAI is usually called an イラスト, 絵, etc. How about:

- ペイントツールSAIで初めて描いたイラスト
- 初めてペイントツールSAIで作った絵